# how to save variables after using header function php

Tags: php, mysql

After i submit a form and save the info to a database i use the header function to redirect to a more user friendly url but the variable **$checkError** is not saving, it gets reset after the header redirect. How can i save the variable even if the page gets refreshed?

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    
// get the post records <<
$id = '2';
$title = $_GET['title'];
$link = $_GET['link'];


// database connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "db_test");

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (id, title, link)
VALUES ($id, '$title', '$link')";

$rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql);


if($rs){
    $checkError = '<div class="success">Success!</div>';
}else{
    $checkError = '<div class="error">Not working!</div>';
}

mysqli_close($con);


//redirect to user friendly url
header("Location: /index.php?id={$id}");

}
```

Comment: to preserve, you can use $_COOKIE or $_SESSION. You should have done some research before you ask. These are basics... and examples are all over the web.. even here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write this to session data and recall it later, as one potential solution.

Modify/add in your example code block:

```
session_start();
if($rs){
    $_SESSION['checkData'] = '<div class="success">Success!</div>';
}else{
    $_SESSION['checkData'] = '<div class="error">Not working!</div>';
}

header("Location: /index.php?id={$id}");
```

And back on index.php, you would need to add/modify:

```
session_start();
if( isset( $_SESSION['checkData'] ) ){ // check whether it's set
    echo $_SESSION['checkData']; // output variable
    unset( $_SESSION['checkData']; // reset variable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$GLOBALS** OR **$_SESSION** as an array for $GLOBALS  more details [click here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php)

you can use it as the below code in your header file

set value in $GLOBALS

```
$GLOBALS['checkError'] = '<div class="success">Success!</div>';
```

get value from $GLOBALS

```
echo $GLOBALS['checkError'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store your data in cookies or sessions before the redirect.

A session is also used to store data, but I suggest you store data in cookies because the session stores data on the server-side, creating performance issues, whereas cookie stores data on the client-side.

You can check the critical difference of [Cookie and Session](https://www.guru99.com/difference-between-cookie-session.html)

*first.php*

```
<?php            
    if($rs){
        setcookie('checkError', '<div class="success">Success!</div>');
    }else{
        setcookie('checkError', '<div class="error">Not working!</div>');
    }
?>
```

*second.php*

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['checkError'])) {
        echo $_COOKIE['checkError'];
    }
?>
```

I hope this is helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, very easy to implement is to skip `$checkError` variable and redirect user to a specific page:

```php
// ...
$rs = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
mysqli_close($con);
$page = $rs ? 'success' : 'failure';
header("Location: /{$page}.php?id={$id}");
```